# Twilio: Put caller on hold

Tags: javascript, php, twilio

Is it possible in twilio to put a caller on hold then the agent can call someone to verify something. Then after verifying the agent will get back to the hold caller.

Thank You,

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you will find most of the information you're looking for [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/09/call-queueing-putting-callers-on-hold-calll-redirect-new-url-new-feature.html). But in summary, using the REST api you can put users on/off hold and do much more.

Using the CallSid you can do anything with a call via the Rest API. Have a look at [Twilio change call state](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) for more information.

You can wait for the agent to press Hold (or any button you choose depending on which experience you're using – VOIP or PSTN) and can then use the REST API to update that call sending it to a queue using the  verb for example.

Then you can retrieve the call using the CallSid to update it and send it back to the agent.

Here's an example of how you could redirect a running call to a different URL that would return a message. you can change that URL to be anything on your server.

```
var accountSid = '{{ account_sif }}';
var authToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls({{ call_sid }}).update({
    url: "https://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    method: "POST"
}, function(err, call) {
    console.log(call.to);
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: how you are getting child_callsid which you mentioned in your ajax ?
`Twilio.Device.incoming(function(connection) {
    $('#callsid').val(connection.parameters.CallSid)
});`
This is what i am doing but instead of getting caller callsid .. i am getting my own

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did.

I have a hold button in the client side. A caller came in and I accepted the call. The caller wants to talk to verify something but the agent doesn't know anything. So the agent told the caller that he will be put on hold. So I clicked the button hold. So what I did, I get the callsid and send it to the php server side.

CLIENT SIDE

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();>agent/call_controls/redirect_to_hold",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:{'CallSid':child_callsid},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
```

PHP SERVER SIDE

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);
    $call = $client->account->calls->get($_POST["CallSid"]);
    $call->update(array(
        "Url" => HTTP_BASE_URL."agent/call_controls/forward_hold",
        "Method" => "POST"
    ));
```

and then I redirected it the hold url.

```
$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml;
    $response->say("You are put on hold");
    $response->play("https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3", array('loop' => 100));
    print $response;
```

The caller is now put on hold. How can I retrieved him again as the agent who put him on hold.

Thank You very much

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11293711)

Comment: I got it. I just use queue for this one.

Comment: @Drex Can you help me , how to use queue for put a call on hold and retrive back from hold

Comment: how you are getting child_callsid which you mentioned in your ajax ?
`Twilio.Device.incoming(function(connection) {
    $('#callsid').val(connection.parameters.CallSid)
});`
This is what i am doing but instead of getting caller callsid .. i am getting my own