# How can i get childSID using parentSID into the twilio

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I am using a Twilio javascript SDK into my application .

Twilio connection always return a parentSID , but in the childSID there is actual data is available , how can i get the childSID using a parentSID , is there any possible way to get a list of childSID ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use Twilio's REST API to return all the child calls of a parent SID. You just need to make a call to the [Calls list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list) and pass a [parent call SID parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters). In Node.js that would look like this:

```
var accountSid = "your_account_sid";
var authToken = "your_auth_token";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls.list({ parentCallSid: "the_parent_call_sid" }, function(err, data) {
    data.calls.forEach(function(call) {
        console.log(call.sid);
    });
});
```

**Edit**

Here's the PHP version you'd need. You'll want to download the [Twilio PHP helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php) and then use this code:

```
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$calls = $client->calls->read(
    array("ParentCallid" => "the_parent_call_sid")
);
// Loop over the list of calls and echo a property for each one
foreach ($calls as $call) {
    echo $call->sid;
}
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: for `require` i need to add require.js file?

Comment: Ah, this is using the REST API from your server. I don't think there's a way to get this in the browser. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to add this in .js file

Comment: Ok, but you need to do this on the server using the REST API. It can't be done in the browser. Above is an example of how you would use Node.js to achieve this on the server. What is your server written in?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the code you could use in PHP.

Comment: Can you help me on this question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425978/put-caller-on-hold-and-retrive-back-from-hold-using-javascript-in-twilio`

Comment: Don't know what you mean, I updated my answer to help.

Comment: Fantastic! Could you mark the answer as correct so that others can see it worked too? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Philnash , i edit your answer , and it is work for me